# cassandra replica exception HUnavailableException

Tags: cassandra, consistency

I have a cassandra 2 datacenter pair with single replication with each datacenter containing a single node and each datacenter located on separate physical servers on the network.  If one datacenter crashes, the other one will continue to be available for reads and writes  I started up my java application, on a 3rd server, and everything it running ok.  It's reading and writing to cassandra.

Next I disconnected, pulled the network cable, the 2nd datacenter server from the network.
I expected the application to continue running with no exceptions against the 1st datacenter, but that was not the case.

The following exception started to occur in the application:

```
me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HUnavailableException: : May not be enough replicas present to handle consistency level.
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ExceptionsTranslatorImpl.translate(ExceptionsTranslatorImpl.java:60)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.KeyspaceServiceImpl$9.execute(KeyspaceServiceImpl.java:354)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.KeyspaceServiceImpl$9.execute(KeyspaceServiceImpl.java:343)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.Operation.executeAndSetResult(Operation.java:101)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.operateWithFailover(HConnectionManager.java:232)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.KeyspaceServiceImpl.operateWithFailover(KeyspaceServiceImpl.java:131)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.KeyspaceServiceImpl.getSuperColumn(KeyspaceServiceImpl.java:360)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.thrift.ThriftSuperColumnQuery$1.doInKeyspace(ThriftSuperColumnQuery.java:51)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.thrift.ThriftSuperColumnQuery$1.doInKeyspace(ThriftSuperColumnQuery.java:45)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.KeyspaceOperationCallback.doInKeyspaceAndMeasure(KeyspaceOperationCallback.java:20)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.ExecutingKeyspace.doExecute(ExecutingKeyspace.java:85)
        at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.thrift.ThriftSuperColumnQuery.execute(ThriftSuperColumnQuery.java:44)
```

Once I reconnected the network cable to the 2nd server, the error stopped.

Here's more details on cassandra 1.0.10

1) Here's the following describe from cassandra on both datacenters

```
Keyspace: AdvancedAds:
Replication Strategy: org.apache.cassandra.locator.NetworkTopologyStrategy
Durable Writes: true
Options: [DC2:1, DC1:1]
```

2) I ran a node tool ring against each instance

```
./nodetool -h 111.111.111.111 -p 11000 ring
Address DC Rack Status State Load Owns Token
1
111.111.111.111 DC1 RAC1 # <-- usUp Normal 1.07 GB 100.00% 0
111.111.111.222 DC2 RAC1 Up Normal 1.1 GB 0.00% 1

./nodetool -h 111.111.111.222 ring -port 11000
Address DC Rack Status State Load Owns Token
1
111.111.111.111 DC1 RAC1 Up Normal 1.07 GB 100.00% 0
111.111.111.222 DC2 RAC1 # <-- usUp Normal 1.1 GB 0.00% 1
```

3) I checked the cassandra.yaml

```
the seeds are 111.111.111.111, 111.111.111.222
```

4) I checked the cassandra-topology.properties

```
111.111.111.111

    # Cassandra Node IP=Data Center:Rack

    # datacenter 1
    111.111.111.111=DC1:RAC1 # <-- us

    # datacenter 2
    111.111.111.222=DC2:RAC1

    default=DC1:r1

111.111.111.222

    # Cassandra Node IP=Data Center:Rack

    # datacenter 1
    111.111.111.111=DC1:RAC1

    # datacenter 2
    111.111.111.222=DC2:RAC1 # <-- us

    default=DC1:r1
```

5) we set the consistencyLevel to LOCAL_QUORUM in our java application as follows:

```
public Keyspace getKeyspace(final String keyspaceName, final String serverAddresses)
{        
    Keyspace ks = null;
    Cluster c = clusterMap.get(serverAddresses);
    if (c != null)
    {            
        ConfigurableConsistencyLevel policy = new ConfigurableConsistencyLevel();
        policy.setDefaultReadConsistencyLevel(consistencyLevel);
        policy.setDefaultWriteConsistencyLevel(consistencyLevel);

        // Create Keyspace
        ks = HFactory.createKeyspace(keyspaceName, c, policy);
    }        
    return ks;
}
```

I was told this configuration would work, but maybe I'm missing something.

Thanks for any insight

Answer (score 1):

Hector is known to return spurious unavailable errors.  The native protocol Java driver does not have this problem: https://github.com/datastax/java-driver

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two nodes and your data would be placed on the node that is actually down, when the consistency is required, you may not be able to achieve full write availability. Cassandra would be achieving that with [Hinted Handoff](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/modern-hinted-handoff), but for the QUORUM consistency level the `UnavailableException` will be thrown anyway.

The same is true when requesting data belonging to the down node.

However it seems like your cluster is not well balanced. Your node `111.111.111.111` owns 100% and then `111.111.111.222` seem to own 0%, looking at your tokens they seem to be a reason for that.

Checkout how to set initial token here : http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.8/install/cluster_init#token-gen-cassandra

Additionally you may want to check [Another Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288841/availability-of-cassandra), which contains answer with more reasons, when the situation like this may happen.

Answer (score 0):

`LOCAL_QUORUM` won't work if you configure `NetworkTopologyStrategy` like this:

```
Options: [DC2:1, DC1:1] # this will make LOCAL_QUORUM and QUORUM fail always
```

`LOCAL_QUORUM` and (in my experience) `QUORUM` require data centers to have at least 2 replicas up. If you want a quorum spanning your data centers you have to set consistency level to data center agnostic `TWO`.

More examples:

```
Options: [DC2:3, DC1:1] # LOCAL_QUORUM for clients in DC2 works, QUORUM fails

Options: [DC2:2, DC1:1] # LOCAL_QUORUM in DC2 works, but down after 1 node failure
                        # QUORUM fails, TWO works.
```